# Rounding Numbers in XML Using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Task Goal: I am pulling data from a column in Excel and converting this information into the XML format.

I want to round numbers which have been extracted from an excel sheet using ruby and I want these to be 0 decimal places instead of 1 decimal places for example 24 instead of 24.0

```
xml.PLZ "#{row[7]}" is the code which produces: 
<PLZ>74544.0</PLZ> in XML
```

I have looked at the .round function but this does not work for me as I am pulling the PLZ value from column 7 of an excel sheet. This PLZ value changes as the program works its way down the excel sheet. What could I do to remove the decimal point in the output?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with round? [#round docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Float.html#method-i-round) say that the first parameter says the decimal place. `123.45.round(0) = 123`. Is this not what you need?

Comment: What do you mean, "the `round` function does not work"?

Comment: You could also use `.to_i` to round *down* to the nearest integer.

Comment: I incorrectly used the .round function outside of the brackets when as stated below I needed to put inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To round to nearest integer:

```
#{row[7].round}
```

To round to specific decimal place use:

```
#{row[7].round(no_of_decimal_place)}
```

example lets say I have a = 2.3456. If I do

```
#{row[7].round(2)} this will give me 2.35
```

Comment: Thankyou, this has resolved my problem. I will accept the answer as soon as it allows me to.

Comment: @George123 no problem :D